# ERROR: Unable to find spider: tutorial

Tags: python, web-scraping

i created a project by command line scrappy and I wrote a spider file with name tutorial.py as follow:-

```
  from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class TutorialItem(Item):
name = "tutorial"
allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
    "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
]

def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

but when I run ' scrapy crawl tutorial' command it's showing 'ERROR: Unable to find spider: tutorial'. Tell me what's wrong here with my code.
Thanks.

Comment: did you put it into a directory ( named tutorial too) and where you should create an empty file named __init__.py?

Comment: Sorry but this project is automatically created by command line.

Answer (score 0):

follow the tutorial again, you are mixing an Item and a Spider definition, in general, scrapy spiders should inherit from `Spider`

```
class TutorialSpider(Spider):
    ...
```

Comment: This class is automatically derived from project. I just create this project by command line, And this class name automatically taken by the project.

Comment: I created this project by 'scrapy startproject myproject' command, And go to myproject directory, After that i run 'scrapy crawl myproject', it's again showing this error.